# Ошибка при работе с Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

пытаюсь начать работать с библиотекой Retrofit,создал интерфейс пишу "@GET"
и сразу ошибка '@GET' not applicable to type,вроде бы все правильно делаю.Вот мой builde.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
}
```

Comment: покажите код интерфейса, может там проблема

Comment: import retrofit2.http.GET;


public interface VideoApi {
    @GET("/videos/fatured");
    
}
но на @GET сразу ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface VideoApi { 
    @GET("videos/fatured")
    Call<Ваш объект> functionName( тут параметры );
}
```

и еще ссылки проверьте, может там ошибка